# netbeans c/c++ build error

Tags: build, makefile

by default main.cpp is created.it gets succefully compiled.but when i add another c++ source file.build fails.that means if more than one file is added,build fails.here is the error

```
"/usr/bin/make" -f nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk QMAKE= SUBPROJECTS= .build-conf
make[1]: Entering directory '/cygdrive/c/Users/Shantanu/Documents/NetBeansProjects/CppApplication_2'
"/usr/bin/make"  -f nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk dist/Debug/Cygwin_4.x-Windows/cppapplication_2.exe
make[2]: Entering directory '/cygdrive/c/Users/Shantanu/Documents/NetBeansProjects/CppApplication_2'
mkdir -p build/Debug/Cygwin_4.x-Windows
rm -f "build/Debug/Cygwin_4.x-Windows/newfile.o.d"
g++    -c -g -MMD -MP -MF "build/Debug/Cygwin_4.x-Windows/newfile.o.d" -o build/Debug/Cygwin_4.x-Windows/newfile.o newfile.cpp
mkdir -p build/Debug/Cygwin_4.x-Windows
rm -f "build/Debug/Cygwin_4.x-Windows/newfile1.o.d"
g++    -c -g -MMD -MP -MF "build/Debug/Cygwin_4.x-Windows/newfile1.o.d" -o build/Debug/Cygwin_4.x-Windows/newfile1.o newfile1.cpp
mkdir -p dist/Debug/Cygwin_4.x-Windows
g++     -o dist/Debug/Cygwin_4.x-Windows/cppapplication_2 build/Debug/Cygwin_4.x-Windows/newfile.o build/Debug/Cygwin_4.x-Windows/newfile1.o 
build/Debug/Cygwin_4.x-Windows/newfile1.o: In function `main':
/cygdrive/c/Users/Shantanu/Documents/NetBeansProjects/CppApplication_2/newfile1.cpp:3: multiple definition of `main'
build/Debug/Cygwin_4.x-Windows/newfile.o:/cygdrive/c/Users/Shantanu/Documents/NetBeansProjects/CppApplication_2/newfile.cpp:3: first defined here
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk:63: recipe for target 'dist/Debug/Cygwin_4.x-Windows/cppapplication_2.exe' failed
make[2]: *** [dist/Debug/Cygwin_4.x-Windows/cppapplication_2.exe] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory '/cygdrive/c/Users/Shantanu/Documents/NetBeansProjects/CppApplication_2'
nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk:60: recipe for target '.build-conf' failed
make[1]: *** [.build-conf] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/cygdrive/c/Users/Shantanu/Documents/NetBeansProjects/CppApplication_2'
nbproject/Makefile-impl.mk:39: recipe for target '.build-impl' failed
make: *** [.build-impl] Error 2

BUILD FAILED (exit value 2, total time: 955ms)
```

Comment: That's not the complete error log, there's some messages missing before the first you show.

Comment: i added the first part.please tell whats the error and how to fix it.

Comment: And now we can see the actual error: `newfile1.cpp:3: multiple definition of 'main'`. That message should be clear enough, you have defined the `main` function more than once, the next line in the log tells you where the other definition is.

Comment: it says it is defined in newfile.cpp.but i want to run newfile1.cpp.how to run only one file? it can be compiled succesfully,and all the options about running a single file are disabled.dont want to run project as a whole.

Comment: when i exclude newfile.cpp containing main defination,newfile1.cpp builds succefully but a window pops up and then i cant see the output.what should i do? help is appreciated.

Comment: If you have two programs, they need to be separate projects. All files in a single project gets linked into a single program.

Comment: i do not understand.what does that mean? so if you have two files in one project with main defined..will you always get such errors.because whenever i create more than one file...in a project..i always get build up error.

Comment: thanks for the help.i am asking too much...will figure out somehow...someway.thanks.

Comment: All files in a single project are linked together into a single program. If you want two separate programs, you need two separate projects.